# Camara not save image

Tags: ios, cordova, camera, ionic-framework

Community'm trying to hold the camera in my iOS application with Ionic, I access the camera and have held multiple codes to display the image and everything works perfectly, the problem is to save the image. I can not keep it on the device and do not know how, I have followed to the letter the tutorials and examples found in internet. Here is the code I'm taking right now so they can see if I'm making any errors.

```
$scope.getPhoto = function() {
var options = {
  quality: 50,
  destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
  allowEdit: true,
  encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  targetWidth: 100,
  targetHeight: 100,
  popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: false
};

Camera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
  var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
  image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}, function(err) {
  // error
});
};
```

As another question, the same subject, anyone knows or has developed applications using these technologies filters to the pictures? I mean, such as Instagram, take a picture and you can change colors, tones, etc. If anyone knows about that subject could guide me or give some source.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the camera option to save the photo with this parameter:

```
saveToPhotoAlbum: false
```

Here is your whole block of code with that line changed:

```
$scope.getPhoto = function() {
var options = {
  quality: 50,
  destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
  allowEdit: true,
  encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  targetWidth: 100,
  targetHeight: 100,
  popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: true
};

Camera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
  var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
  image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}, function(err) {
  // error
});
};
```

Hope that Helps! Good luck!